# Circle packed by tangent circles

Tags: geometry, circles

The circles are tangent two by two.
The radius of the largest circle is 2.
We have to calculate the radius of the two smaller ones.

[image]

I am able to calculate the distance based on the following sketch:

[image]

Let $x$ be the unknown distance. Then it follows that:
$AM=1+x$, $OM=2-x$, $OA = 1$. From Pythagorean theorem $AM^2 = OM^2 + OA^2$. Substituting and solving for $x$, the radius is found to be $2/3$.

My question is how we can justify geometrically the construction. How M is defined as the center of the small circle and why MO is perpendicular to AO (in order to be allowed to apply Pythagoras' theorem).

Instructions say that: "The construction of the figure is a problem in itself, which can be proposed after the calculation, as an application of Thales' theorem." but I cannot figure how to apply the theorem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Center of the smallest circle needs to be equidistant from the smaller circles which means it needs to be equidistant from the centers of the smaller circles. So it's on the perpendicular bisector.

Comment: @Vasya Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the center of the other circle B, you can argue that $\triangle AMO$ and $\triangle BMO$ are congruent due to same lengths on all sides.

Then, $$\angle MOA = \angle MOB = 180/2 = 90$$

Therefore, $MO$ is perpendicular to $AO$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was something I thought about. But I don't get the given instructions that accompanied the problem statement: "The construction of the figure is a problem in itself, which can be proposed after the calculation, as an application of Thales' theorem."

Comment: Yeh, sometimes, instructions could be distracting

Comment: @Dimitris Probably it is just a construction of the line that is $2/3$ of a given line (assuming you know the answer is $2/3$). Have you done similar constructions in the past? If not, this should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem#Dividing_a_line_segment_in_a_given_ratio

Comment: Otherwise, without the calculation, to construct a circle touching three given circles is possible, but certainly not trivial. Look up problem of Apollonius: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius

Comment: @StinkingBishop I know the intercept theorem (or Thales' theorem). I guess the instructions want to justify geometrically the construction. No to justify the $2/3$. The exercise is from a basic engineering mathematics course which I teach some fundamental geometric/trigonometric skills.

Comment: @Dimitris Is it possible that the problem was simply to (a) calculate $2/3$ and (b) use this result and the intercept theorem to construct the smaller circle (e.g. by constructing point $M$ which divides the corresponding radius in the ratio $1:2$)? Has your problem been originally posed in English? - if not, I guess a bit of the meaning could've been lost in translation.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Actually I guess you are right. I will proceed like this. Thanks again for the useful comments.